# Важность (приоритет) символов при сравнении (1 > 'a')

Tags: mysql, sql, сравнение

В качестве примера приведу код из SQL, который сейчас изучаю:

```
SELECT * FROM anytable WHERE 1 > 'a';
```

В выводе будет целая таблица.
В то же время команда:

```
SELECT * FROM anytable WHERE '1' > 'a';
```

ничего не выведет.
Собственно и интересует, почему `1`, как и любое другое число, больше чем `'a'`? Но в то же время `'1'` меньше?

MariaDB 10.3.13

Comment: Во втором случае всё просто: код символа `1` меньше кода символа `a`. По аналогии `'b' > 'a'`, `'B'<'a'` и `'100'<'20'`

Comment: @andreymal тут еще вопрос, что к чему приводится. `'a'` к коду символа, или все же `1` к строке

Comment: Во втором случае `'1'` изначально строка, и там ничего ни к чему не приводится. А про первый случай не знаю

Comment: я про первый случай и говорил. Только про первый. Почему вы решили, что будут сравниваться именно кода символов?

Comment: Если бы вы и правда говорили только про первый случай, то вы бы вообще не стали писать второй случай в тексте вопроса :) Почему `'1'` меньше чем `'a'` — я ответил. Если вы мне не верите, никто вам не запрещает проверить экспериментально.

Comment: А про первый случай [нашлось в документации](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html): строка приводится к числу, и из `'a'` получается `0`

Comment: @andreymal действительно. Немножко непривычное поведение. Признаю вашу правоту. Вы  оформите это ответом чтоли)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что в `MySql` автоматически приводятся типы.
В случае запроса

```
SELECT * FROM anytable WHERE 1 > 'a';
```

ваше `'a'` автоматически приводится к числу и получает значение `0`. По этому `1 > 0` всегда принимает значение `True` и отображаются все записи. Подробнее в [документации](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html)

Для большей наглядности можно выполнить запрос

```
select CAST('a' AS SIGNED)
```

вернет `0`.

Во втором запросе

```
SELECT * FROM anytable WHERE '1' > 'a';
```

сравниваются символы. Код символа `a`(97) больше кода символа `1`(49), по этому ничего не выводится.

Для большей наглядности выполните запрос

```
select ASCII('1') one, ASCII('a') a
```

Comment: Для полноты ещё бы добавить пояснения по [Collation Coercibility in Expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-collation-coercibility.html)

Comment: В пояснениях всё хорошо и доступно аргументировано.